# How to organize broker message redelivery in ActiveMQ for PHP Stomp client

Tags: php, activemq-classic, messaging, stomp

I'm trying to implement a broker redelivery with ActiveMQ 5.8.0 and PHP Stomp extension. But this doesn't work as expected.

PHP subscriber that rollbacks messages

```php
define('QUEUE_NAME', '/queue/Task.Test');

$stomp = new Stomp();

$stomp->subscribe(QUEUE_NAME, array(
    'activemq.prefetchSize' => 10,
));

while (true) {

    $tid = uniqid('tid');
    $stomp->begin($tid);

    try {
        $frame = $stomp->readFrame();
        if ($frame) {
            print_r($frame->headers);
            $stomp->ack($frame->headers['message-id'], array('transaction' => $tid));
            echo "Get message {$frame->headers['message-id']}, rollback it", PHP_EOL;
            $stomp->abort($tid);
        } else {
           $stomp->commit($tid);
        }
    } catch (StompException $e) {
        $stomp->abort($tid);
    }
}
```

ActiveMQ config (scheduler is enabled):

```xml
    <plugins>
        <redeliveryPlugin fallbackToDeadLetter="true" sendToDlqIfMaxRetriesExceeded="true">
            <redeliveryPolicyMap>
                <redeliveryPolicyMap>
                    <redeliveryPolicyEntries>
                        <!-- a destination specific policy -->
                        <redeliveryPolicy queue=">" maximumRedeliveries="2" redeliveryDelay="10000" />
                    </redeliveryPolicyEntries>
                    <!-- the fallback policy for all other destinations -->
                    <defaultEntry>
                        <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" initialRedeliveryDelay="5000" redeliveryDelay="10000" />
                    </defaultEntry>
                </redeliveryPolicyMap>
            </redeliveryPolicyMap>
        </redeliveryPlugin>
    </plugins>
```

With that config subscriber receives all mesages and rollbacks them, so they returned to the queue, but I want them to be redelivered after some delay. There is special status for ACK: "poison ack" but I don't know how to specify it.

How can I enable redelivery on the broker side?

Comment: you have already got a redeliveryDelay on your redeliveryPolicy. What do you want more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, redelivery requires NACK command that is defined in [STOMP Protocol version >=1.1](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#NACK). PHP Stomp client supports only version 1.0, so it's impossible to enable redelivery for this extension. However, it's easy to extend Stomp class with `nack()` method and headers handling. Hope, that this information will be helpful for someone.